# Run list of validation functions over a single input with fp-ts

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am using [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/) to handle validation in my application. I want to write a function that accepts a list of validators and runs all of them over a single input.

These are the types I want to use:

```js
import { Either } from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import { NonEmptyArray } from "fp-ts/lib/NonEmptyArray";

type Validation<E, A> = Either<NonEmptyArray<E>, A>;
type Validator<E, A> = (a: A) => Validation<E, A>;

declare function validations<E, A>(vs: Validator<E, A>[], a: A): Validation
```

Internally I want `validations` to be implemented in terms of [fp-ts `Validation`](https://dev.to/gcanti/getting-started-with-fp-ts-either-vs-validation-5eja). I'm following the example, but it requires to know the list of `Validator`s statically, when I want to produce that list dynamically.

Notice that for simplicity I'm making the Validation type take a NonEmptyArray of errors, since I'm mainly interested on how to combine the validations from a dynamically constructed array.

Finally, if the list of validations is empty, we can assume the input is valid.

How can I implement `validations` using the combinators provided by `getValidation` from `fp-ts`